# Structure of database for representing connections between users

Tags: database, database-design, connection

In the app that I am trying to build, there will be users (stored in a users table), and users can 'connect' to one another (e.g. like being friends on Facebook). What I am trying to do is build the data structure for storing these connections. The data will mainly be used for presenting a 'connections' (e.g. friends on Facebook) table for a user. So far I have came across 2 different approaches for doing that:

1. Creating A table for each user which has all his connections (e.g. friends).
2. Having one table representing ALL the connection in the website (for example:

[Row 1 = John-Kyle]

[Row 2 = Kyle-Bob]

[Row 3 = Lilli-John]

etc....).

My question is - which one would be more efficient (mainly in term of query time, but also in terms of size). I guess the second one would be much smaller in size, but would take a lot more time to query... What do you think? Which one is better to use? If you have any idea which model is more widely use (especially by popular websites like Facebook, Instagram etc.) that would also help a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are good reasons outside performance not to go with the first approach, but even performance is unlikely to gain from this approach:

1. Out of many tables, the DBMS first needs to find the right table, and only then it can search it.
2. One table can be searched in just one index seek.

So you have a ***search for the table + small index seek*** versus ***just one large index seek***. Searching for the table is unlikely to be faster than the "top half" of the large B-Tree descend, and many separate tables may lead to a lot of "slack" (i.e. pages that are not completely filled), diminishing the cache effectiveness. For both of these reasons, the (2) is likely to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

one table with all conncetions. with each row having user a , user b , connection type. where the connection type is a reference to another table listing connection types. add proper indexes.

Comment: wouldn't it take a lot of time to query through that though?

Comment: no if you index it properly. having one table per user is unclean. cthulhulike.